# How to increase the accuracy of measurements in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to resize a pdf to a specific size, but when I use scaling it loses accuracy because a float rounds the value. Is there a way that I can resize a pdf with a given width and height? This is what I've tried so far:

```
public void PDFScalingTest11(string FileIn, string FileOut)            
    {
        // The following code opens a pdf and place it 20 times on a new pdf page
        // I want to resize the pdf before adding it

          int iQuantity = 20;
          int iCol = 3;
          int iRow = 0; 
          float fTileSpacing = 0;

          float fPrintWidth = 1200f; // Page Width 
          float fPrintHeight = 4158f; // PageHeight

          float fWidth = 400f; // output size
          float fHeight =  594f;

          float fPdfWidth = 210f;// current pdf size
          float fPdfHeight = 297f;

          float fScalingWidth = fWidth / fPdfWidth; // scaling (this value should be (1.904761904761905) but is rounded to (1.90476191)
          float fScalingHeight = fHeight / fPdfHeight; // this value is correct  

          fPrintWidth = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(fPrintWidth); // change mm to points         
          fPrintHeight = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(fPrintHeight);

          fWidth = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(fWidth);
          fHeight = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(fHeight);
          fTileSpacing = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(fTileSpacing);

        float x = 0;
        float y = (((fHeight + fTileSpacing) * iRow) - (fTileSpacing + fHeight));

        using (var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(fPrintWidth, fPrintHeight)))
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(FileOut, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    doc.NewPage();
                    iDraw = 0;
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FileIn);
                    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
                    PdfTemplate tmp = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);

                    for (int i = 0; i < iQuantity; i++)  
                        {
                            canvas.AddTemplate(tmp, fScalingWidth, 0, 0, fScalingHeight, x, y);
                            x += fTileSpacing + fWidth;
                            iDraw++;

                            if (iDraw == iCol)
                            {
                                y -= fHeight + fTileSpacing;
                                x = 0;
                                iDraw = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    doc.Close();
                    }                        
            }
        }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FileOut);
    }

    // The width of each pdf added to the new pdf page is 399mm instead of 400
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, post your code and maybe a jsfiddle so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ByteBuffer` class has a public static variable named `HIGH_PRECISION`. By default, it is set to `false`. You can set it to `true` so that you get 6 decimal places when rounding a number:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.HIGH_PRECISION = true;
```

That will cost you some performance (but maybe you'll hardly notice that) and the resulting file will have more bytes (but measurements will be more accurate).