# iTextSharp PdfContentByte AddTemplate

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to use scaling in iTextSharp PdfContentByte AddTemplate

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
cb.AddTemplate(page, scalex, 0, 0, scaley, x, y);
```

It works, but scalex с and scaley rounds. If scalex = 1,04776, in output file form 100 мм I obtain eaxactly 105 mm, not 104,776 mm.
If the opportunity to get 104,776 mm in output file?

Comment: In the iText 5.5.x code I see nothing that rounds that value. To make the issue reproducible, therefore, please supply example code and an input PDF file or at least a result PDF of such a transformation to analyze. And please indicate how you are measuring as sometimes the measuring tool itself is the problem...

Comment: All here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CUbnyxgbct-EaP2KLuMreISxkUSvPk3I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Measuring tool is Enfocus PitStop.

Comment: Please try setting `iTextSharp.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.HIGH_PRECISION = true` before executing that code. Does the result differ?

Comment: Yes, the result is different and fine. Many thanks! Is there an analogue for iText 7?

Comment: Have you observed the same issue with iText 7?

Comment: Yes. I observed the same issue with iText 7. But your advice solved this problem too.  Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing floating point numbers to the content streams iText offers two modes, normal and high precision. In the normal mode iText rounds the numbers using some irregular pattern; in case of numbers between 1 and 32767 it rounds to at most 2 decimals.

Your `1.04776` is in that range, so it is rounded to `1.05`.

In iTextSharp 5.x you can switch to the high precision mode by setting

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.HIGH_PRECISION = true;
```

Read also [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863327/1729265).

In iText 7 there is a similar static variable, `iText.IO.Source.ByteUtils.HighPrecision`. As it is declared internal, you cannot directly change it, but there are static methods in `iText.IO.Source.OutputStream` for that:

```
public static bool GetHighPrecision()
{
    return ByteUtils.HighPrecision;
}

public static void SetHighPrecision(bool value)
{
    ByteUtils.HighPrecision = value;
}
```

Thus, to switch to high precision mode here call

```
iText.IO.Source.OutputStream.SetHighPrecision(true);
```